# How to pipe a node stream into a RethinkDB table

Tags: node.js, stream, rethinkdb, piping

Is there any convenient way to **pipe a NodeJS stream into a RethinkDB table?**

I'm thinking something similar to [this](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-copy-streams) for PostgreSQL:

```
pg.connect(function(err, client, done) {
  var stream = client.query(copyFrom('COPY my_table FROM STDIN'));
  var fileStream = fs.createReadStream('some_file.csv')
  fileStream.pipe(stream).on('finish', done);
});
```

Imagine you have large amounts of data and want to pipe it to a RethinkDB database using streams, what's the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out the third-party driver [RethinkDB Dash](https://github.com/neumino/rethinkdbdash#writable-streams) which has writeable streams. The official driver doesn't implement the stream interface currently, but we may be doing it in the near future

Comment: I just added an example doing import/export with streams in case you're interested in a snippet -- https://github.com/neumino/rethinkdbdash-examples/tree/master/import-export